# On submit, store form value in variable, then display it in a second form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Working on a simple issue here. In the end the project will take a user's submitted name and capitalize the first two letters.

However for now I'm just trying to store the user's input in a variable and then display the exact same thing in a "results" form. Not sure where I'm going wrong.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ever/DQn57/

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"     
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">   
</script>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
    <script src="application.js"></script>
    <title>Tim's Name Capitalizer!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Name Capitalizer</h2>

    <div class="intro">
    Welcome! Enter your name below (first and last) then press "SUBMIT" to see 
what happen!
    <br>
    </div>

    <br>    

    <form>
    Enter Here:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="enteredFormName" placeholder="Your 
Name">
    </form>
    <br>

    <form>
    Result:
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="fixName" id="fixedFormName" placeholder="Your  
Name">
    </form>
    <br>
    <button>Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
div.intro{
font-weight: bold;
width: 50%;
}

form.questions{
text-align: left;
font-size: 25px;
width: 500px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 5px;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

     //when the <submit> button is clicked
     $('button').click(function(){

     //store the user's entry in a variable
     var enteredName = document.getElementById('enteredFormName').value;

     //update the html in the second form to show the user's entered name
     $('#fixedFormName').value(enteredName);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/dwebexperts/U68ny/2/

Replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

     //when the <submit> button is clicked
     $('button').click(function(){

     //store the user's entry in a variable
     var enteredName = document.getElementById('enteredFormName').value;

     //update the html in the second form to show the user's entered name
     $('#fixedFormName').value(enteredName);
    });
}
```

with this:-

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

         //when the <submit> button is clicked
         $('button').click(function(){

         //store the user's entry in a variable
         var enteredName = document.getElementById('enteredFormName').value;
         //OR var enteredName = $('#enteredFormName').val();
         //update the html in the second form to show the user's entered name
         $('#fixedFormName').val(enteredName);
        });
    });
```

You also have an issue at the closing of `"  $(document).ready(function(){ "`, you are closing it with `}` this only whereas, it requires `});` at the end.

Comment: Good catch, thank you DWX. Question: I'm new and find these little mistakes to be both hard to catch and potentially devastating. Is there a trick of the trade to help find them? For what it's worth, I use SublimeText. Thanks!

Comment: Well, what I think is you just have to take care of code as only small things create big issues in programming[like starting and closing of brackets, semi-colons, etc].

Answer (score 0):

why are you mixing normal js with jquery ?

```
 var enteredName = $('#enteredFormName').val();    
 $('#fixedFormName').val(enteredName);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I mixed them because I'm new and probably don't know better :P Question: why does SublimeText not want to use <val>? It shows it as white text, and it instead wants to auto-complete it as blue and using <value>. Thanks for any beginner tips.

Comment: probably SublimeText doesn't have autocomplete code support for jquery

Answer (score 0):

Just try this

```
$(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
         var data = $("#enteredFormName").val();
         $("#fixedFormName").val(data);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the jQuery my friend.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    //when the <submit> button is clicked

    $( "button" ).click(function() {

             //store the user's entry in a variable
             var enteredName = $('#enteredFormName').val();

             //update the html in the second form to show the user's entered name
             $('#fixedFormName').val(enteredName);
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

**Jquery :**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('#button').click(function(){
      var enteredName = document.getElementById('enteredFormName').value.toUpperCase();
$('#fixedFormName').val(enteredName)
        });
    });
```

**Demo :**

http://jsfiddle.net/C9gGq/